# Filling missing dates for certain weekdays only

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 sets of employees who either work on Monday, Wednesday, and Friday, or Tuesday, Thursday, and Saturday.
I have lists of working dates for several employees, but some are missing as they were not logged in.

I tried to work on a formula that inserts the missing dates based on the workdays set (either M,W,F or T,Th,S). The missing date should be inserted as a new row, as the currently logged dates have information in conjugate columns. I also wanted it to ignore if someone worked on a day that he should not work on, and fill in the missing dates based on the current schedule.

Here is the sample data:

This employee works on MWF.

```
9/11/2023
9/13/2023
9/15/2023
9/18/2023
9/20/2023
9/22/2023
11/1/2023
11/3/2023
11/6/2023
11/8/2023
11/10/2023
11/13/2023
11/15/2023
11/17/2023
```

As you can see, there is a gap between 9/22/2023 and 11/1/2023.
I want my macro to add the missing dates between these dates only if they were M, W, or F.
The desired results should be:

```
9/11/2023
9/13/2023
9/15/2023
9/18/2023
9/20/2023
9/22/2023
9/25/2023
9/27/2023
9/29/2023
10/2/2023
10/4/2023
10/6/2023
10/9/2023
10/11/2023
10/13/2023
10/16/2023
10/18/2023
10/20/2023
10/23/2023
10/25/2023
10/27/2023
10/30/2023
11/1/2023
11/3/2023
11/6/2023
11/8/2023
11/10/2023
11/13/2023
11/15/2023
11/17/2023
```

Preferably, highlighting the newly added rows.
For T,Th,S it would be the same thing.

Sample T,Th, S

```
4/6/2023
4/8/2023
4/11/2023
4/13/2023
4/15/2023
4/18/2023
4/20/2023
4/22/2023
4/27/2023
4/29/2023
5/2/2023
5/4/2023
5/9/2023
5/11/2023
5/13/2023
5/18/2023
5/23/2023
5/25/2023
```

Desired output:

```
4/6/2023
4/8/2023
4/11/2023
4/13/2023
4/15/2023
4/18/2023
4/20/2023
4/22/2023
4/25/2023
4/27/2023
4/29/2023
5/2/2023
5/4/2023
5/6/2023
5/9/2023
5/11/2023
5/13/2023
5/16/2023
5/18/2023
5/20/2023
5/23/2023
5/25/2023
```

I tried to edit the code from: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68469264/vba-for-excel-to-fill-missing-weekdays-in-a-range-and-mark-new-mondays)

My code turned out to be:

```
    Sub FillDays()
    Dim dict As New Collection, cl As Range, arr, cur, nxt, mst
    arr = Split(("3 5 7"))
    For cur = 0 To UBound(arr)
        dict.Add cur, arr(cur)       'make the dict name:index, key = name, e.g. "Sunday":0 to get the index by name
    Next
    
    Set cl = ActiveCell   'get the start cell
    Do While True
        cur = cl.Text     'get the text from the current cell
        cur = Weekday(c1)
        Set cl = cl.Offset(1)           'move to the next cell
        nxt = cl.Text    'get the text from the next cell
        nxt = Weekday(nxt)
        On Error Resume Next
        cur = dict(cur + 3)       'get the index of the day of the week from the current cell
        nxt = dict(nxt + 3)       'get the index of the day of the week from the next cell
        MsgBox nxt
        'if the cells do not contain the day of the week or is empty >> exit
        If cur = "" Or nxt = "" Or Err.Number <> 0 Then Exit Do
        On Error GoTo 0
        mst = (cur + 1) Mod 3   'calculate the proper index for the next cell
        MsgBox mst
        If mst <> nxt Then      'if expected weekday <> next weekday
            'add the expected weekday and shift to the next cell
            cl.EntireRow.Insert ' side effect: shifts the cl to the next row
            Set cl = cl.Offset(-1)  'compensate for the side effect
            cl.Value = WorksheetFunction.Proper(arr(mst))   'Capitalized name
            If mst = 1 Then cl.Offset(, 1) = "New"  'a new cell with value "Monday" is created
            cl.Resize(, 2).Font.Bold = True 'debug
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

But the formula didn't add the missing dates or even just the number of the weekday.

I believe the solution to this problem is to implement Workday.intl function and to use "0101011" (MWF) or "1010101" (TThS) to tell Excel what are the days of interest.

Thank you.

Comment: *it didn't work* is a meaningless problem description. Please be **specific** about the problem you're having, and ask a **specific question** related to the code you've posted.

Comment: Edited. I want to insert missing dates of certain days per week in a certain date column. I added screenshots.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) You really should go back and read the [help] pages again.

Comment: It happened because copying and pasting from Excel generates images automatically. I  tried to add it to a table but could not. I hope putting the data into a code bracket is not a problem. Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Assuming data is on Col A and all dates are in `certain working days`

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    Dim arrRes(), iR As Long, iCnt As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long, iDate As Date
    Dim eDate As Date
    iR = -1
    With ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        iDate = CDate(.Range("A1"))
        eDate = CDate(.Cells(LastRow, 1))
    End With
    Do While iDate <= eDate
        iR = iR + 1
        ReDim Preserve arrRes(iR)
        arrRes(iR) = iDate
        iCnt = VBA.Weekday(iDate, vbMonday) / 2
        iDate = iDate + IIf(iCnt = 1, 2, iCnt)
    Loop
    ' Change B1 to A1 if you want to overwrite the 1st col
    ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Resize(iR + 1, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(arrRes)
End Sub
```

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Weekday function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/weekday-function?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vblr6.chm1009058)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [Range.Resize property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.resize?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144187)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

[image]

---

Update:

-
As long as you don't mix "TTS" with "MWF" in a list, the code is compatible with either "TTS" `OR` "MWF."

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    Dim arrRes(), iR As Long, iCnt As Long, i As Long
    Dim iDate As Date, eDate As Date, iOffset As Long
    iR = -1
    With ActiveSheet
        iDate = CDate(.Range("A1"))
        eDate = CDate(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    End With
    iOffset = VBA.Weekday(iDate, vbMonday) Mod 2
    Do While iDate <= eDate
        iR = iR + 1
        ReDim Preserve arrRes(iR)
        arrRes(iR) = iDate
        iCnt = (VBA.Weekday(iDate, vbMonday) + iOffset) / 2
        iDate = iDate + IIf(iCnt = 1, 2, iCnt)
    Loop
    For i = 0 To iR
        If Not CLng(CDate(Cells(i + 1, 1).Value)) = CLng(arrRes(i)) Then
            Rows(i + 1).Insert
            Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = arrRes(i)
            Cells(i + 1, 1).Interior.Color = vbYellow
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Your code was able to reproduce the desired sample, however, it doesn't work on different dates, for example: 
3/25/2023
3/28/2023
3/30/2023
4/1/2023
4/4/2023
4/6/2023
4/8/2023
4/11/2023
5/6/2023
5/6/2023
5/16/2023
5/18/2023
I think it has to do with vbMonday, as it doesn't indicate certain days (Tuesday, Thursday, Saturday).

Comment: Please clarify the meaning of `doesn't work`. I've uploaded a new screenshot about the test data in your comment. I've not seen any issues.

Comment: I had to try it on another sheet and it worked perfectly! thank you! How can I switch to a Monday, Wednesday, Friday schedule? Also, how can I insert the new date as a new raw? Thank you again.

Comment: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwLrQ.png). On 5/12, it became offset as there was an extra day. I want it to ignore the non-working days and only add T,Th,S or M,W,D based on my choice.

Comment: `Monday, Wednesday, Friday schedule` What's the difference with the current schedule (the output of my answer)? What's `new raw`? Please edit your post to show expected output.

Comment: `5/12` is Friday ( not in T,Th,S or M,W,D ), so it is not in the output. Is there anything wrong?

Comment: My apologies, you are correct as 5/12 is Friday. To be clear (I'll add in the question stem), I have 2 sets of working days, either M,W,F or T, Th, S. Sometimes, the employee can work extra day in non-working days for his schedule. "Raw" was a spelling mistake, I meant Row. I want the macro to insert the missing dates in between the correct dates as a new row. Your code worked well on T, Th, S schedule, but gave different output if the employee had M,W,F schedule.

Comment: How to know which set working schedule ( MWF / TTS ) is used to extend (or insert) date  list? eg. 3/25/2023, 3/29/2023, 1/4/2023, the 1st and 3rd are TTS, the 2nd is MWF. Please share a sample date list with expected output and clarify the logic in original post. The sample data needs to be representative and able to cover data characteristics.

Comment: I just updated my question, thank you for your patience. I know which schedule each employee has, so I assume two macros are needed.

Comment: You don't need two macros. I‘ve updated the code with row insertion.